# Does Resolve<T>() return objects per-session?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unity-container, ioc-container

In Microsoft Unity IoC, if I call `Resolve<SomeType>()`, can I guarantee that the object returned is the one that was created during the current session?

For example, three users sign on, and let's say that the object of `SomeType` that gets created in the container has different values for each user. Will a call to `Resolve` return the object that was created for the current user? Or would it do something stupid like return the last one that was created?

I'm having troubles testing this myself due to some environment problems and I need to check something in soon, so if someone could answer this it would be very helpful!

**Edit**

Forgive me for I am very new to Unity, but based on [what I read here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649975.aspx), it seems like I should be able to register objects in the container with a unique name and retrieve them by that name. So, wouldn't I be able to use a session ID or some other value that persists within a session to retrieve my object?

Comment: It seems as though you want to use Unity as a cache if you are registering instances against a 'key'. This is not really what Unity is best at\for, and may be why the answers you are getting are confusing.

Comment: If you do use Unity as a cache what happens when you have a web farm, or what happens when ASP.Net worker processes recycle?

Comment: In addition to what @chibacity said, you are opening yourself for a world of hurt if you are sharing instances between different threads. Which thread serves a particular request is entirely non-deterministic and you would need to synchronise left right and center when you want to access it. Really, creating new objects, evern if it requires a trip to the DB is not THAT expensive.

Comment: @Igor Unity is threadsafe and if objects are partioned on a key that relates to a session, then they will not be shared amongst threads concurrently. A session spans requests, but on one thread at a time. I agree though, there is plenty of deep water to be considered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oh wow, lifetime management using Unity in am MVC app. Where do I start?

First of all, session singletons are not really possible as there is no ASP.NET system that will guarantee that the same instance will be used between requests in the same session. The session can mimic the same object persisted within the session by serializing and deserializing it between requests.

Transient instances - i.e. simple registrations without lifetime management specification are sufficient 99% of the time. This implies that an instance of registered type will be created every time it is needed.

It is very rarely that you need instances to live throughout the lifetime of the request. However when you need those, you **really** need those. A connection to a DB is a perfect candidate for this. Request singletons, on the other hand are much easier to create and manage.

The most elegant solution is to use Unity's child container feature. A child container can be created at the beginning of the request, disposed at the end of the request (as an added bonus it will dispose all `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager` instances).

When creating a child container, all registrations are still available from the parent container, so you need to register request specific stuff with the child container.

Here is pseudo-code to get this working:

```
private void Application_Start() {
  _parentContainer = new UnityContainer();
   //creates a transient registration, available at any point in the app.
  _parentContainer.RegisterType<IParentIntf, ParentIntfImpl>();
  ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new ServiceLocatorControllerFactory());
}

private void Application_BeginRequest() {
  var childContainer = _parentContainer.CreateChildContainer();
  //registers a request "singleton"
  //This registration is a type registration, an instance of RequestInterfaceImpl
  //will be created when needed and then kept in the container for later use.
  childContainer.RegisterType<IRequestInterface,RequestInterfaceImpl>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
  //save the child container in the context, so we can use it later
  HttpContext.Items["childContainer"] = childContainer;
}

private void Application_EndRequest() {
  //dispose the child container
  ((IUnityContainer)HttpContext.Items["childContainer"]).Dispose();
}
```

One other thing that needs to be done is to override the Controller Factory to use the child container to create controllers. Controller are the first point of entry into the application and they could simply take a dependency on other components in their constructor.

```
public class UnityControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory {

    #region IControllerFactory Members

    public override IController CreateController(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName) {
        IController controller;
        controllerName = controllerName.ToLower();
        var container = ((IUnityContainer)HttpContext.Items["childContainer"])
        if(container.IsRegistered<IController>(controllerName))
            controller = container.Resolve<IController>(controllerName);
        else 
            controller = base.CreateController(requestContext, controllerName) ;
        return controller;
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP states that he wants session-scoped not request-scoped. But I agree (as I mentioned in my last comment), that request-scope should be considered.

Comment: Yes, I've just realised that.

Comment: A fat +1 for describing the serialization problems with session variables in ASP.NET. This is something many developers don't realize until they have to scale out their application to multiple servers and have to start using an out of process session store. And then you're screwed.

Comment: Where does the `_parentContainer` variable come from? Do you save this as an ASP.NET application variable, like `Application["ApplicationContainer"] = _parentContainer;` and then retrieve it from there in BeginRequest? Or is it a static variable somewhere? I was trying this as a non-static member variable in the Application class in global.asax but it doesn't work (it is `null` when `Application_BeginRequest` is reached although it was set in `Application_Start`).

Comment: From my experience it **has** to be a static variable inside Application, because you might get two instances of application. When that happens, you still get one start event. I am sure this is explained by how IIS apppools work, but I haven't dug into it in detail.

Comment: Thanks for response! In the meantime I have chosen *Unity.Mvc3* from CodePlex. It's a litte Unity 2.1 addon which manages all that stuff. It seems that the parent container reference is hold in the `DependencyResolver` of MVC3, so storing and retrieving it is managed by the MVC runtime itself - cool, I don't need to care :)

Answer (score 2):

The default behaviour will be to return a new instance for each resolve call, this isn't what you want.

It would be possible to create and resolve the same instance within a session, but there is no built in support as far as I know. You would have to write your own lifetime manager, and then use this when registering your type.

There is a lifetime manager that can do per thread instances, but this isn't useful for sessions as threads will get re-used, and resolve would need to also work across multiple requests to be truly session-scoped.

It's entirely possible that someone has written a lifetime manager for this.

Comment: @Samo how are you registering the object, what lifetime manager are you using? If you use RegisterInstance, then of course you will get the same instance back.

Comment: I was mistaken about my previous comment (there was some initialization happening) so I deleted it. I'm using RegisterType, since different products use the same code and will be registering different classes in the container. Is there approach that addresses both of my needs? The LifetimeManager is a ContainerControlledLifetimeManager

Comment: @Samo There is nothing out-of-the-box that will give you session-scoped instances (it would have to integrate with ASP.Net session sate management which could be in-memory or SQL Server, etc, and this is something that Unity does not do on its own) . `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager` will actually give you a singleton i.e. a single instance shared by all callers of `Resolve`. How are you managing your container e.g. is it a static?

Comment: @Samo It would probably not be too painful to come up with a lifetime manager that could resolve on a request-scoped basis. Session-scoped is much more involved.

Comment: @chibacity: see my recent edit, do you have any input on this?

Comment: @Samo Are you familiar with the ins and outs of session state management and the difference between a session and a request? You can use named instances with Unity, and access them via 'keys' from your different sessions, but you are really only then using Unity as a cache i.e. a key\object store. This will only work well if you have a single server, but this is not really what Unity is best at i.e. being a cache, ASP.Net has built-in stuff for that. I'm used to thinking of things in terms of multiple servers and the complexity  that comes with it.