# Unity Share Single Instance Between Multiple Objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container

While working on some test application , I faced a scenario where I want to share one instance of a class among other instances through Unity .

I have a interface called ICommon and this is been implemented in Common class .
I have two other interfaces IInterface1 and IInterface 2 and the have been implemented in Class1 and CLass2 . But Class1 and Class2 has a dependency on ICommon and this dependency gets resolved through Unity . But my problem is they are not sharing the same instance rather they it's creating multiple instances of ICOmmon . So I am looking for something through which Unity will share the same object if it's created already or will create a new one .

public interface ICommon
    {
        void Method1();
    }

```
public class Common : ICommon
{
    public void Method1()
    {
        return;
    }
}


public interface IInterface1
{
    void Function1();
}

public class Class1 : IInterface1
{
    private readonly ICommon _common;
    public Class1(ICommon common)
    {
        _common = common;
    }
    public void Function1()
    {
        return;
    }
}

public interface IInterface2
{
    void Function1();
}

public class Class2 : IInterface2
{
    private readonly ICommon _common;
    public Class2(ICommon common)
    {
        _common = common;
    }
    public void Function1()
    {
        return;
    }
}

public static void RegisterComponents()
{
    var container = new UnityContainer();
    container.RegisterType<IInterface1, Class1>();
    container.RegisterType<IInterface2, Class2>();
    container.RegisterType<ICommon, Common>();

    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
}

public class Test
{
    private IInterface1 _interface1;
     private IInterface1 _interface2;
    public Test(IInterface1 interface1, IInterface2 interface2)
    {
        _interface1 = interface1;
        _interface2 = interface2;
    }
}
```

So I want one instance to be created for ICommon and would be shared between Class1 and Class2 .

Answer (score 1):

You must use ContainerControlledLifetimeManager for singleton. Please refer the below link for complete details.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ff647854.aspx

```
    // Register a default (un-named) type mapping with a singleton lifetime
    container.RegisterType<ICommon, Common>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
    // Following code will return a singleton instance of MySingletonObject
    // Container will take over lifetime management of the object
    container.Resolve<ICommon>();
```

Comment: It would be singleton for all request I mean the same instance would be shared for all user request or just for that request . I am using EntityFramework and I have put some code in ICommon(Ex: IDataBaseFactory) to get a instance of my DbContext and want to share the same DbContext instance among my Repository and UnitOfWork so that UnitOfWork can commit what ever entitie I have added or updated in my repository , So I just want to make sure this is just for that request not all user request or else chances are there data would be conflicted if multiple users access the same DbContext .

Comment: This question might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651844/does-resolvet-return-objects-per-session

Comment: What I get to know from the above link is it ContainerControlledLifetimeManager will create a singleton object and would be shared across multiple instances but that's exactly what I dont want . I want instances to be per call specific . There are some code to resolve this but that is for a controller .

Comment: Will PerThreadLifetimeManager or HierarchicalLifetimeManager is going to work in my scenario ? I ll test with these  .